# tableViewにカスタムセルを表示したい。

Tags: swift, xcode

**自作したカスタムセルを自分の画面に表示したいのですが表示されなのは何故なのでしょうか。**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```swift
class TableViewSkillController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var addSkill: UIBarButtonItem!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    self.myTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "TableViewCell")

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell") as! TableViewCell

        cell.skillName.text = "〇〇〇〇〇〇"
        cell.goalCountNumber.text = "20 : 00"

        return cell
    }

    @IBAction func addSkillButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    }


}
```

```swift
import UIKit

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var skillName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var goalCountNumber: UILabel!


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }




    @IBAction func ToEachSkillButton(_ sender: Any) {


    }


}
```

↑↑これからコードの中身を入れるつもりです。

Comment: カスタムセルが表示されない原因はいろいろ考えられるんですが、あなたの画面キャプチャーを見ると、セル自体が1つも表示されていないと言う可能性もありそうです。まずはブレークポイントか`print`文を置くかして`TableViewSkillController`の`tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`メソッドが呼ばれているか確認してみて下さい。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

解決しました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ですがそもそも

```swift
 self.myTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "TableViewCell")
```

の`nibName:` の`TableViewCell` と　`forCellReuseIdentifier:` の `"TableViewCell"` が同じ名前に足らない様に上の画像の**赤丸枠**内の　identifier の名前を違う名前に設定することが大切な様に思いました。(例えばcustomTableViewCellにするなど)

そうすると

```swift
 self.myTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "customTableViewCell")
```

となり

```swift
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customTableViewCell") as! TableViewCell

        return cell
    }
```

となるのでわかりやすくこの様なことに悩まづにすみました。

Comment: 無事に解決できたようでおめでとうございます。ただし、出来るだけ悩まずに済ませようと思ったら、カスタムセルを定義するのに独立したxibは使わず、storyboard上でProtoType Cellsを追加するのが今風です。(xibを使うのはかなり古めかしいやり方。) `UITableView`はiOSプログラミングでは非常に多用されるものなので、少し時間をとってでも、そちらも練習しておかれることをお勧めしておきます。

Comment: お久しぶりです‼︎  そうなのですか、、、てっきりxibを使う方が難易度が高く後々為になるのかと思ってしまっていました。　早速、ProtoType Cells を使用したやり方に切り替えようと思います。

Comment: 難易度が高い、と言うよりは、単に手間が増える、と言うのが私の個人的感想です。xibを使うやり方も将来役に立つことがあるでしょうが、今は`UITableView`なり`UICollectionView`なりをバンバン使ってみたくはならないですか?WWDC'19で発表されたSwiftUIなんてものが普及したらどちらも古臭いやり方とか言われそうですが、今は手間のかからないやり方から試してみた方が良いと思います。(Xcodeがおバカなせいで面倒に感じることもたまにあるかもしれませんが…。)

Comment: WWDC`19は気になってはいたのですが初心者には無縁の事だと全く触れずにいたのですが此度のOOPer様のコメントでぜひ調べてみようと思いました。　ProtoTypeCells に切り替えてみたのですが　` ViewDidLoad()` の　` UINib `の処理がなくなるのでより簡潔になりましたのでこちらを使っていきたいと思います。

Answer (score 1):

`TableViewSkillController`クラスの中、

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell") as! TableViewCell

   cell.skillName.text = "〇〇〇〇〇〇"
   cell.goalCountNumber.text = "20 : 00"

   return cell
}
```

3行目を

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
```

と書き換えてみてください。
引数に`for: indexPath`がついているほうのメソッドの返り値が非オプショナル型（`UITableViewCell`）であるのに対し、ついてないほうのメソッドの返り値がオプショナル型（`UITableViewCell?`）であることに注目してください。

Comment: ありがとうございます　すいません、書き換えてみたのですができませんでした。

Comment: では、原因は*ほかにも*あります。

Comment: 左様ですか。　私には皆目見当もつきません。。　どの様な理由で  for : indexPathがいるのでしょうか。

Comment: う〜ん。バグを見つけ出すことができるのは、当事者である質問者さん以外ないというのは、厳然とした事実なんですけどね。その当事者が「皆目見当もつきません」では、この場をお開きにするしかありません。Never give up、ですね。（回答追加してます）

Comment: ありがとうございます。Never give up とても大切ですね。　無事解決いたしました